# what is syntax for using iter function

Tags: r

I have no documentation or knowledge of how to run a iter command. The question is as follows:

Run the `kc$iter` command. Include the command, output screenshot, and
explain what the output shows.

```
# set seed
set.seed(12345)

# Cluster analysis
kc<-kmeans(myvehicle, 4)
kc

# Iteration
kc$iter(kc(myvehicle), )
```

The last command is a guess and I got an error message: Error: attempt to apply non-function. I don't know what the syntax is and the example I used and it had a value of 12 after the comma. However, I don't know why so I left it blank. I couldn't find anything that describes how to use this function.

Comment: `kc$iter` should be enough.

Comment: It's not a function, it's an argument of the object, the definition of which you can easily find in the documentation `iter 
The number of (outer) iterations.`

Comment: It returned the following info

Comment: ``` [1] 3``` I don't know how to interpret that